# Vue JS Return Data Property From Method to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am having an issue with my Vue app on returning a particular data value from my method to my HTML to be rendered.

The full code can found be here https://github.com/Callum9362/temp-converter/blob/main/src/App.vue

My problem is with line 62. I can return the variable result to the console, but the value is staying at 0 on the page. I am also not getting any errors, which is not helping me solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`result` in `convert()`](https://github.com/Callum9362/temp-converter/blob/41fba86/src/App.vue#L83) is passed as an argument value (not a reference to the component's data prop). To change the component's `result`, use `this.result`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    convert(fromValue, option, result) {
      this.result = /* new value */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to the `result` value for click event. You have to set the `result` value of `data`. Inspite of returning the `result` you need to set the result as `this.result=result`

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-euler-rqf5j?file=/src/App.vue)